# Find parent with single child with the same name

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<root>
 <parent>
  <name>Luiz</name>
  <son><name>Luiz</name</son>
  <daugther><name>Cristina</name></daughter>
 </parent>
 <parent>
  <name>Cristina</name>
  <daugther><name>Cristina</name></daughter>
 </parent>
 <parent>
  <name>Carolina</name>
  <daugther><name>Cristina</name></daughter>
 </parent>
</root>
```

What XPath can I use to test a parent to see if it has only one child (elements son or daughter) which has the same name as itself. In the example above only the second parent (Cristina) would have validated the test. It is worth mentioning that I might have many other elements besides son, daughter, parent and name.

Comment: What about the first `parent` with `name` being "Luiz"? It has only one child which has the same name as itself? Do you want to exclude that because there is a `daughter` with a different name?

Comment: Yes, I need to be able to tell whether there is only one child (be it a son or a daughter) and that this child is named after its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What XPath can I use to test a parent to see if it has only one child
>   (elements son or daughter) which has the same name as itself.

**Use**:

```
         /*/parent
               [count(*[self::daughter or self::son]) =1
              and
                name = *[self::daughter or self::son]/name
               ]
```

This selects all children of the top element that are named `parent`, have only one child element (except the `name` child) and the string value of their `name` child is the same as the string value of the `name` child of their other (non-`name`) child.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
         "/*/parent
               [count(*[self::daughter or self::son]) =1
              and
                name = *[self::daughter or self::son]/name]
        "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (with numerous errors corrected to make it well-formed):

```
<root>
 <parent>
  <name>Luiz</name>
  <son><name>Luiz</name></son>
  <daughter><name>Cristina</name></daughter>
 </parent>
 <parent>
  <name>Cristina</name>
  <daughter><name>Cristina</name></daughter>
 </parent>
 <parent>
  <name>Carolina</name>
  <daughter><name>Cristina</name></daughter>
 </parent>
</root>
```

**it evaluates the XPath expression and outputs all selected nodes** (in this case just one):

```
<parent>
   <name>Cristina</name>
   <daughter>
      <name>Cristina</name>
   </daughter>
</parent>
```

Comment: This don't work for me, as I said above: _"It is worth mentioning that I might have **many other elements** besides son, daughter, parent and name."_

Comment: OK, then you could have done something to provide a more realistic example. See the updated answer.

Comment: That does work indeed, I was hitting a dead end because I was trying to get the nodes, then count the result, and then fetch the name... thanks.